# onTouchEvent never called MapActivity

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have an activity which extends MapActivity. But when I tap the map, the onTouchEvent never gets called. Why is this?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("temp", "onTouchEvent");
    return true;
}
```

edit: I now have these 2 methods in a custum created ItemizedOverlay to catch my events.
The first one gets called when I tap an overlay. But the second (onTouchEvent) never get's called when I touch the map.

```
@Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      this.movement = true;
      Log.d("temp", "overlayItem tapped" + item.getTitle());
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
        this.movement = false;
        Log.d("temp", "overlayItem tapped finish");
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MapView` associated with a `MapActivity` almost certainly handles the view for you.  If you look at the docs for `Activity#onTouchEvent()` it says: "Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

I'm guessing what you want to do with that touch event is already handled by the `MapView`, maybe find the right place to put it inside of that code?

Comment: "Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it" Yes that is indeed the problem. But I can't add a custom listener then. I'd have to change the MapActivity class. Looks like there must be an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the touch event?

Comment: I'm trying to change the place of an itemized overlay. First I catch the onTap event in a custom made class which extends ItemizedOverlay (like in a google tutorial). Then I try to get the new touchEvent in the MapActivity class

Comment: I understand the first part, but not the second.  What will you do with this new touch event?  Since you will be outside the context of your MapView, I'm not sure how useful it will be to handle it there. Can your action not be handled by your subclass of MapView's onTouchEvent method?

Comment: . Can your action not be handled by your subclass of MapView's onTouchEvent method? That's what I'm trying by implementing onTouchEvent in my custom Mapactivity (public class MyOwnMap extends MapActivity).

Comment: Sorry, in MapView, not MapActivity.  (or ItemizedOverlay which also implements the onTouch method)

Comment: I tried this in ItemizedOverlay but it does not work. Check beginpost for an update of the code.

Comment: Try returning false from your onTap method, maybe it'll fall through to your onTouchEvent method?

Comment: Yes it does. Only now I get three events in a row when I tap. And when I keep my finger on it the events keep on coming. I'm going to try Flavio's approach.

Comment: Figured it out by using onTap and onTouchEvent in custom overlay. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

You should override [dispatchTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Answer (score 0):

The handler isn't being executed. I didn't find the exact reason for this behavior yet. Probably the reason is that the MapActivity doesn't automatically forward the event to the registered MapView or it just doesn't get notified about the event, since the motion event actually occurs on the MapView itself and not its parent, the MapActivity.

What can be done instead is to either register the event directly on the MapView
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return false;
  }
});
```

..or to override the MapActivity's dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent). What has to be considered however is to appropriately forward the event in this case.