# need help clearing touch events between activities

Tags: android

**Scenario:**

There are two activities...
Activity A has an imagebutton to launch an intent to show Activity B on screen.
Activity B has an imagebutton to finish() itself and cause Activity A to be shown.
These buttons are at the same location on each activity

**Problem:**

in Activity B, when I double-tap the button (instead of single tap), Activity A becomes visible but quickly shows Activity B again !

the second touch event seems to carry through to Activity A and it would seem that I could fix this problem by clearing some touch buffer in onCreate() of Activity A.

How can this be done? Or is there another fix ?

I've reproduced this on the emulator (2.2) and on the phone (2.3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double tap isn't really a common android event. It sounds like your click is not coming through one activity to another (which I think is impossible) but that you are clicking once on B and once on A.

What you could do is in onActivityResult() capture the time, and don't like people click the imagebutton for like 0.3seconds or something after the activity result.

Comment: for my described problem to occur I have to tap really fast on Activity B. The activity-to-activity animation shows. Then, without touching, Activity A will launch Activity B.

Comment: The touch events get queued by the system, it's entirely possible that touch1 is delivered, animation completed, touch2 delivered at a delay later. Override onTouchEvent in your activity and log the event and the activity that is capturing it.



You

Comment: yes, that seems to be happening. If I could clear touch2 during the onCreate() then that would fix it.

Comment: Actually no, because onCreate won't be called if your activity is returning. on ActivityResult will if you startActivityForResult. Maybe onResume() will be called.

Comment: onResume() is the better place. To get the timestamp when the Activity starts/resume use SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(). Within onTouch() use event.getEventTime(). It turns out that the MotionEvent's trigger within 200ms. I was hoping that the MotionEvent timestamp would indicate having been triggered BEFORE the activity resume'd, but sadly these events contain a timestamp AFTER onResume was called. On the whole, this problem seems to stem from a race-condition within the OS. I do wish there was a way to flush the input-buffer :O

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. Surprisingly, there is very little information about this on the web. My solution combines the comments from this question and [onTouchEvent never called MapActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718624/ontouchevent-never-called-mapactivity):

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/** Stores the time (as per SystemClock.uptimeMillis()) of the last
* call to onResume() in order to filter out touch events which occurred before
* the activity was visible. */
private long resumeTime = 0;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    resumeTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventTime() < resumeTime) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Discarded touch event with time earlier than onResume()");
    return true;
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Comment: This works. I have implemented this even more drastically: I don't update the timestamp in onResume, but in a OnGlobalLayoutListener(). If you do it in onResume but the root view of the incoming activity is heavy and takes time to be laid out, the issue may still happen.